# How to solve for the inverse of $f$ for a floor function? I really need to learn the method.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function, inverse-problems

I was doing some exercises on discrete maths and came across this question I don't know how to solve, nor can I find any relevant examples in my book.

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $f(x) = ⌊x/2⌋$, if $T = \left\{3, 4, 5\right\}$ , then what's the inverse of $f (T)$?

I know how to get $f (T)$ but how to get its inverse? Could anyone teach me please?

Comment: Do you mean inverse image of $f(T)$?

Comment: Yes, I think. The question doesn't specify inverse image but I'm guessing it's so.

Comment: $f(T)=\left\{ 1,2 \right\}$. What real numbers are taken to either $1$ or $2$ by $f$?

Comment: Yes, I know f(T)={1,2}. I wrote the question exactly as it is. They didn't give me any more data. I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question. I really need to learn how to solve these type of things

Comment: You did not answer my question. Which real numbers are mapped by $f$ to $1$ or $2$?

Comment: 3 to 1; 4,5 to 2? 3 and 5's f(T) was floored down. Is that what you mean? [3,5)?

Comment: Any $x$ such that $2 \leq x < 6$ is mapped to $1$ or $2$ by $f$ and no other real numbers. Thus the inverse image of $f(T)$ (which is the set containing $1$ and $2$) is the interval $2 \leq x < 6$.

Comment: Is this the answer? If yes, could you please explain how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: What is exactly that you do not understand? Can you see that all numbers in $2 \leq x < 6$ are mapped to $1$ or $2$ by $f$? Can you see that any $x$ not in this interval is not mapped to $1$ or $2$? The problem was to determine the inverse image of $f(T)$, i.e., the set of reals that are mapped into $f(T)$ (which is just the set containing $1$ and $2$), i.e., the set of reals whose image under $f$ is either $1$ or $2$.

Comment: I get your point now, I was actually expecting we could do it with some formula like how we do for normal bijective functions. It wasn't mentioned whether they wanted inverse image of f(T), just find the inverse. So, I sort of got confused. I get it it has to be done on a case to case basis. Thank you very much for all your help, and also for being patient with me. Good day.

Comment: Note that $f(T)$ is a set. A set cannot have an inverse. Functions have inverses.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}{c}
   f & : & \Bbb R & \to & \Bbb R \\
     &   &      x & \mapsto & \left\lfloor \dfrac x2 \right\rfloor
\end{array}$

Before we start trying to solve equations, let's try to see a pattern. I looked for a few of the largest intervals that get sent into a few integers.
\begin{align}
   [0, 2) &\to 0 \\
   [2, 4) &\to 1 \\
   [4, 6) &\to 2
\end{align}

It seems that, for $n \in \Bbb Z^+$,  $f^{-1}(\{n\}) = [2n, 2n+2)$

Can you finish this?